# Call Angularjs directive in other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i create a directive and it is reusable. but when i use it in a controller scope not work. 
example:

```
 <my-directive ... > </my-directive>// work correctly
<div ng-controller='myController'>
 <my-directive ... > </my-directive> // not work 
</div> 
 <my-directive ... > </my-directive>// work correctly
```

Update question

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    url: '@',
    name:'@'
    //other ...
},
controller: ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
}],
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
}
```

Comment: You are probably have scoping issues, depending on how you created your directive. The scope can be shared, inherited or isolated. Unfortunately without more information about the error and your expected result(s) its hard to try and help.

Comment: Post your directive here

Comment: @ NexusDuck i post directive.

Comment: @HJZ What exactly doesn't work? What did you expect, and what did you get instead?

Comment: @NexusDuck my directive fetch data from data base.when use it in a controller display this error Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?

Comment: @HJZ I don't see your directive fetching any data with the code you provided us

Comment: i post part of code. complete code is https://github.com/JustGoscha/allmighty-autocomplete

Comment: @ NexusDuck i add url to fetch data from data base.